# I was doing a Distinct Values java Program. I attempt on the Error

Tags: java, compiler-errors, distinct-values

This a Method I am using with my Program

```
static int check(int pos) {
    int i, flag = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < pos; i++) {
        if (a[pos] == a[i]) {
            flag = 1;
            return 1;
        }
    }
    if (flag == 0)
        return 0;
}
```

When I compile it, I get the following Error:

> Distinct.java:16: error: missing return statement
>   }
>   ^
>   1 error

Comment: The flag is unnecessary. Just return 1 from the loop when you get a match and return 0 at the end of the function.

Comment: You should indent your code properly if you are asking people to try and read it.

Comment: the compiler just found a path that is not returning anything: if the condition of the last `if` is false there is no return - the compiler did not figure out that flag will always be zero there...

Answer (score 1):

what would happen when neither

```
if (a[pos] == a[i])
```

nor  `if (flag == 0)` conditions are met?

then you have a code that is not covering all possible cases, your method have to return something no matter which condition met!!

Comment: and your return is inside an if condition....

Comment: If the first condition is never met, then flag is always 0 so the program can't reach the end of the function without a return statement. Of course the compiler doesn't analyze the code this far so it can't know that.

Comment: This Method is to check whether the Element postion passed has the same element before it . Return 1 says the element is present (that is Duplicate Element before the position 'pos') . Return 0 says that the element is not present(that is it is a Unique Element)